# How to make <ul> <li> <tag1> <tag2> display inline?

Tags: html, css

How to make all tags inside `<li>` inline ? 
Like on screenshot:

[image]

There's link on the page where it need apply this solution.
http://vk-magazin.com/products/krossovki-adidas-1

sourse code:

```
<h6 class="product-section-title">Размеры</h6>

<ul>
  <li>
    <input checked="checked" id="products_1025786064_97292824" name="products[1025786064]" type="radio" value="97292824" />
     <label for="products_1025786064_97292824">
     <span class="variant-description">
         Color: Green, Size: M
      </span>
     </label>
   </li>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have your label tag display as block in `all-0b8239987d681e98cf22b9d4fd156db2.css`, you can override it by adding to you styles

```css
#product-variants label {display:inline;}
```